# Should this Sympy 1.0 code print True instead of None?

Tags: sympy

The variable `xx` is made positive by assumption.
Therefore exp(xx) > 1 and exp(xx)-1 must be positive.
There seem to be similar examples on this page that return derived results:
http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/

I understand relations don't work right yet in Sympy 1.0.
Have I run into that issue indirectly here?

```
# Should this Sympy 1.0 code print True (or why not?)
# This code prints `None'
from sympy import *
from sympy.assumptions.assume import global_assumptions
xx=symbols('xx')
xxPos= Q.positive(xx)
with assuming(xxPos):
    print(ask(Q.positive(exp(xx)-1)))
## None
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple: assumptions on ranges are **not implemented**. The only allowed subranges of real numbers are positive, negative, nonpositive and nonnegative intervals.

Your expression *exp(xx)-1* is an *Add* object containing an *exp* object and *-1* as addends. To have an idea, look at the code handling the positive assumptions for *Add*:

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/sympy-1.0/sympy/assumptions/handlers/order.py#L267

The evaluation of the positivity *Add* is clear from the code:

- it makes sure that the expression is a real number first (i.e. not a complex).
- if any term in the addition is negative, it returns *None*.
- otherwise it counts the number of nonnegative terms in the addition: if they are less than the number of terms (i.e. there are some positive terms), it return *True*, otherwise *None*.

In your expression there's a negative number, so the for loop will be interrupted, the default value *None* will be returned.

**NOTE**

This description may be appear to lack the case in which all terms are negative. The pointed function returns *None* in that case, which is later handled by the SAT solver and determined to be *False*.

Comment: Assumptions on ranges only applies to assuming things on ranges. The assumption itself is on a single symbol.